# Кроссплатформенная разработка приложения на основе сайта

Tags: flutter, react-native, мобильные-приложения, кроссплатформенность

Стоит задача "Создать кроссплатформенное приложение". Я ищу способ как это можно сделать на React Native или Flutter. Я пробовал делать приложение в Android Studio, там я создавал стандартный макет приложение и используя определенные функции вставлял ссылку на сайт. После чего компилировал приложение в АПК и устанавливал себе на телефон. Получалось мобильная версия сайта(как и надо), только как приложение.

Такой вопрос - реально ли такое сделать на React Native или Flutter? Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста как, а если нет, то подскажите есть ли какие-то другие способы сделать приложение не создавая его с нуля?

Comment: Flutter приложение можно скомпилировать под веб. Насчет React Native - не знаю

Comment: @МихаилРебров, о как, спасибо большое. А знаете как это можно сделать(процесс всего этого)? Может знаете где об этом можно узнать по подробнее?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/web, https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Comment: [React Native WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview)